# Put associated classes in separate source files

Tags: java

I have two classes, `User` and `Wallet`. If I put them in a single file, everything works fine. How can I put them in separate files like `Wallet.java` and `User.java`?

When I tried `User.java` threw an error because it didn't not know what `Wallet` was.

```
public class Wallet{
    float winningAmount;
    float bonusAmount;
    float depositAmount;
    public Wallet(float winningAmount, float bonusAmount, float depositAmount){
      this.winningAmount = winningAmount;
      this.bonusAmount = bonusAmount;
      this.depositAmount = depositAmount;
    }
    public void debitBonus(float amountToDebit){
      this.bonusAmount = this.bonusAmount - amountToDebit;
    }
    public void debitDeposit(float amountToDebit){
      this.depositAmount = this.depositAmount - amountToDebit;
    }
    public void debitWinnings(float amountToDebit){
      this.winningAmount = this.winningAmount - amountToDebit;
    }
   }
```

```
public class User{
    int id;
    String name;
    String email;
    String mobileNumber;
    boolean isVerified;
    Wallet wallet;
    User(int id, String name, String email, String mobileNumber,Wallet wallet){
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.email = email;
      this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
      this.isVerified = false;
      this.wallet = wallet;
    }
  }
```

Comment: you need to use import statement to import Wallet in your User class. e.g improt org.Wallet if Wallet class is in org package/folder

Comment: you can put them in different files and just import the package name of Wallet inside User

Comment: *"will throw an error"* - **what** error?

Comment: Moreover, this is no design pattern but a simple object composition.

Comment: If you're compiling on the console, compile them with the same statement, something like ``javac Wallet.java User.java``

Answer (score 0):

If both files are in the same package it should work immediately.

If they are in different packages, just add an `import` statement to import `Wallet` into `User`:

**User.java**

```
package com.domain.package1;

import com.domain.package2.Wallet;

public class User {
    Wallet wallet;
}
```

**Wallet.java**

```
package com.domain.package2;

public class Wallet {
}
```